# Why is this statement about separable degree true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, separable-extension

I have the following problem:

> Let $E$ be separable over $k$. Consider the tower $$k\subset k(\alpha_1)\subset...\subset k(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$$Then since each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k$ each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k(\alpha_1,...\alpha_{i-1})$ for $i\geq 2$.

And I somehow don't see why this is ture. So I know that since $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k$ we have $$[k(\alpha_i):k]=[k(\alpha_i):k]_S$$ where $[k(\alpha_i):k]_S$ is the separable degree. But why is then $$[k(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_i):k(\alpha_1,...\alpha_{i-1})]=[k(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_i):k(\alpha_1,...\alpha_{i-1})]_S~~~~~~~~(1)$$
Could someone explain this to me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you really mean $[k(\alpha_i) : k(\alpha_1 , \dots, \alpha_{i-1})]$? Or $[k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1}, \alpha_i) : k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})]$?

Comment: So in the book they wrote $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1})$ but yes it seems a bit weird because afterwards they use the tower theorem,i.e. the theorem of multiplication of degree, but this does't work either with my equality $(1)$. Do you know the book S.Lang. There I found the statement on page 241.

Answer (score 1):

The statement " each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})$" means that we have to look at the extension
$$k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})(\alpha_i)/k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})$$

Then we can either use the multiplicative property of the separable degree to get to the result or (what I would prefer) just use the definition of separable elements. An element $\beta \in L$ is called separable over $k$ (where $L/k$ is a field extension) iff its minimal polynomial has distinct roots in an algebraic closure $k^a$ of $k$.
Now the minimal polynomial of each of the $\alpha_i$ is separable over $k$ (by assumption that $\alpha_i$ are separable over $k$).

This will also be true over $k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})$ as this field is bigger and contains more possible scalars, so
$$\text{minpol}_{\alpha_i,k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})} \mid \text{minpol}_{\alpha_i,k}$$
the minimal polynomial over $k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})$ will be a divisor of the (separable) minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $k$. That means that it also has to have distinct roots in $k^a$ and that $\alpha_i$ is also separable over $k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{i-1})$

Comment: So our definition of seperable elements is the following: An element $\alpha$ algebraic over $k$ is said to be separable over $k$ if $k(\alpha)$ is separable over $k$, i.e. $[k(\alpha):k]_S=[k(\alpha):k]$. So is there also a way to work with this definition?

Comment: So I correted my equality $(1)$ from above but I think with respect to my definition I need to show that this equality holds right? But where do I use the equality $[k(\alpha_i):k]_S=[k(\alpha_i):k]$?

Comment: It would be very nice if you could give me a hint.